# How to pass global variable in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

Let say I have a $_SESSION['password'] and a javascript function.

Here's the javascript function:

```
<script>  
    function check() {
        var password = '<?php echo $_SESSION; ?>';
        alert(password);
        if (document.FormName.password.value != password)
            alert("password does not match");
    } 
</script>

<html>
//form here
</html>
```

How come when the alert pop-ups, it will only display nothing? what happened? Is my passing of variable wrong at all?

Comment: Seriously? you alert the password back?

Comment: $_SESSION is an array.

Comment: Check the resultant html in browser. May be `password` is not set in SESSION. And you did not echo $_SESSION['password'] like you say in question.

Comment: see how to show code in question

Comment: This is very wrong. Please don't ever write out the password along with the HTML sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is an array and this will return blank if you echo it.

You should use the

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['password']; ?>
```

It will echo the password that store in Session.

Comment: Concise and explains the problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function check() {    
        var password = "<?=$_SESSION['password']?>";//you forgot ['password'] here       
        alert(password);
        if(document.FormName.password.value != password)
            alert("password does not match");
    } 
</script>

<html>
//form here
</html>
```

Comment: how come I still come up with an error after doing just this var password = '<?php echo $_SESSION['password'] ?>'; alert(password); alerts nothing